# Streaming upload of a base64 image using retrofit

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2, okhttp

I have an upstream server that accepts image submissions using rest. The submitted image is part of a JSON payload similar to this one

```
{
  "name": "Blah.jpg",
  "uploader": "user1",
  "image": "<base64.....>"
}
```

Using this strategy works for small images but generates Out of Memory errors on larger images.

Is it possible to stream the base64 component of the image? Pass in something like an iterator that will be used to read chunks of the image, base64 them and send them directly to the network?

Comment: Would it be possible to upload files directly using `POST` not wrapping the blobs in JSON payloads?

Comment: Consider to use tus to send image, it's designed for it and it allows to resume interrupted transfers. Your current solution is actually worst possible, note that base64 string is approx 1.5x larger than your source image. You should upload image with tus and provide tus upload id in your json

Comment: Thanks for the comments. We are thinking of asking our Upstream to redesign the API and allow us to post directly as @LyubomyrShaydariv says. The reason for the embedded base64 image was to make a single HTTP call to pass the image and image metadata. We'll probably have to make 2 Calls in the new API.

Comment: Heads up - I edited the accepted answer with what ended up working best for me.  I ran into some last-minute problems with Android SDK's Base64 encoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with the following, in a class that extends `okhttp3.RequestBody`:

```
private void writeFile(File file, BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
    byte buf[] = new byte[3000];
    try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        while (fin.read(buf) >= 0) {
            byte encoded[] = Base64.encodeBase64(buf);
            sink.write(encoded);
        }
    }
}
```

It uses <strike>Android's `android.util.Base64`</strike> Apache Commons' `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` to encode a buffered chunk of data.

I ended up writing the other json fields separately, with enough granularity that I could insert the file record exactly where I needed to.

**EDIT:**

As you can see in my edits above, I ended up switching to Apache `commons-codec`, via `compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5'` in my `build.gradle` file.

I didn't have time to investigate why the Android SDK solution didn't work. I tried their `Base64.encode(buf, Base64.NO_WRAP)` as suggested elsewhere - supposedly equivalent to Apache Commons' `encodeBase64(byte[])` - but this did not work, hence the switch.

The problem could have been on our backend, so don't rule out Android SDK's solution based on my post alone - I just wanted to add this note so readers can see the code snippet that actually worked for me in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Not with Gson or Moshi. Both of these libraries require strings to be in memory before emitting them to a stream.