# Retrofit/OkHttp removes Transfer-Encoding header

Tags: java, http, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I need my request to contain header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. But no matter whether I add it with `@Headers` annotation to the method or with `@Header` annotation and a parameter, it will simply disappear from the final request.

```
@POST("/api/upload").                   // this header is added correctly
@Headers({"Transfer-Encoding: chunked", "Content-Type: application/foo"})
Call<UploadResponse> uploadFoo(@Body RequestBody body)
```

or

```
@POST("/api/upload").
@Headers("Content-Type: application/foo")
Call<UploadResponse> uploadFoo(@Body RequestBody body, @Header("Transfer-Encoding") te)
```

and calling it like

```
uploadFoo(body, "chunked");
```

does not work.

Why does retrofit remove this header for no reason?

The header is present in the interceptor, by the way.

Also the `Call` object's `originalRequest` field contains the header, but the `Response` object's `rawResponse.request` does not, even though all other headers are fine.

Comment: Hi, I would like to help you, but I'm not sure to understand your issue. If the request contains the "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" when you call uploadFoo, then, the retrofit lib applies correctly your implemented code. The response headers are provided by your API server.

Comment: @bdzzaid The issue is that the `Transfer-Encoding` header that I add in the annotation is missing from the final request. It appears that it gets removed somewhere inside the http library. I think it gets removed automatically, but I need a way to force it to be there.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, according to http/2 protocol specification, I'm not suprised to see disappeared the transfer-encoding header ( see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding ). Can you try to print the used protocol (**rawResponse.protocol()**) ?

Comment: @bdzzaid it is `http/1.1`

Comment: Okay, let me see what's append, can you tell me what's the version of retrolib you've downloaded ?

Comment: @bdzzaid it is `com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0`

Comment: I tried you're code, and it's working fine. If I print : response.raw().request().headers().get("Transfer-Encoding") I get "chunked".
Can you post more of your code, expecially the way you're calling "uploadFoo" ?

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov I think you mean `response header` is not being showed as `chunked`, right?

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov Can you checkout this small project https://github.com/bdzzaid/stackoverflow-java/blob/master/src/main/java/retrofit/SimpleService.java, replace the "Github interface" on class retr with your post method and share the console output please ?

Comment: Yes, I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, thanks everyone for help, but we've solved the issue by updating server to be able to handle requests without this header. Unfortunately I can't spend more time in this one. I'll probably avoid using retrofit or okhttp in cases where I need more control over the contents of http requests.

Comment: This guy sent a chunked stream of data with retrofit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44788324/4438007 ; I'll try something like that tomorrow and post an answer if successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible, as it is determined by OkHttp insides and depends on the type of RequestBody.

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit provides two options to define HTTP request header fields: static and dynamic.

By this way you are passing static request header, you can see this header in log also if you use logging interceptor

```
@Headers({"Transfer-Encoding: chunked", "Content-Type: application/foo"})
@POST("/api/upload")                  
Call<UploadResponse> uploadFoo(@Body RequestBody body)
```

and the second way is passing  dynamic header, you can also see this header in log

```
@POST("/api/upload")
Call<UploadResponse> uploadFoo(@Body RequestBody body, @Header("Transfer-Encoding") String te)
```

last but not least, if you need the header field including its value on almost every request, you can use an interceptor to add this piece of information, like

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();  
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {  
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        // Request customization: add request headers
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked"); // <-- this is the important line

        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});

OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
```

now the tricky part is here,if in your interceptor you use this `.header(key, val)` then this will override headers, even if there is already an existing header with the same key identifier. You can add multiple request headers with the same key using `.addHeader(key, val)`

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I tried all of those approaches but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, the normal way to do this is using the @Chunked annotation before the @Body.

```
Call<UploadResponse> uploadFoo(@Chunked @Body RequestBody body)
```

Optionally, you can use the Service method to force sending the content as chunked :

```
Service.sendChunked(@Chunked @Body Repo repo);
```

Those are defined in the [ChunkingConverter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/2851c14578a7722da56fabbee8d71e1c8e50c145/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/ChunkingConverter.java)

Comment: This appears to be for retrofit 1, not retrofit 2.

Comment: My bad, I missed this in the original question's comments